# Assigning a popup URL to a PHP variable

Tags: php

I am trying to bypass a piece of code by replacing the on-click function with simply opening an Elementor popup.

Can somebody please talk me through this code?

```
public function display_delete_action( $post ) {
    if ( $post->get_status() === 'pending_payment' && ! empty( $this->pending_orders[ $post->get_id() ] ) ) {
        return;
    }
 
$delete_url = add_query_arg( [
      'action' => 'delete',
      'post_id' => $post->get_id()
    ], wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'my' ) );
 
    printf(
        '<li class="cts-post-action-delete">
            <a href="%s" class="post-dashboard-action-delete">%s</a>
        </li>',
        esc_url( wp_nonce_url( $delete_url, 'my_dashboard_actions' ) ),
        __( 'Cancel', 'my' )
    );
}
```

I can see that $delete_url is being created using the arguments at the top and then called with the esc_url at the bottom.

What I cannot figure out is how to replace the URL with:
"#elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI4NzIzIiwidG9nZ2xlIjpmYWxzZX0%3D"

I tried:

```
 $delete_url = "#elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI4NzIzIiwidG9nZ2xlIjpmYWxzZX0%3D"
```

but to no avail.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show us your on-click function.

Comment: Ok, I have edited.

Comment: How are you calling this `on-click` function? You can't call PHP functions from JavaScript (without Ajax)

Comment: Sorry I did not write the function, I am just trying to change what happens when I click on the "Cancel" button which is outputted from the Printf

Comment: Well I'm not sure if this is the correct way but I got it to work by editing this line:
esc_url( '#elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjI4NzIzIiwidG9nZ2xlIjpmYWxzZX0%3D'),